# Get Touch Coordinates from a Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, touch, uigesturerecognizer

Hi I am using the below snippets to get X and Y coordinates of touch and name of ViewController in a given class:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Began: %@ X location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.x);
    NSLog(@"Began: %@ Y location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.y);
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Ended:%@ X location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.x);
    NSLog(@"Ended:%@ Y Location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.y);
}
```

Initially I wanted to do it only for two ViewControllers but now I want to do it for all the classes. Do I have to write these snippets in every class to do the needful or can I use a singleton instance?

This is my Singleton class code:

```
QuestionAlert.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuestionAlert : NSObject
+(id)sharedManager;
@end

QuestionAlert.m

#import "QuestionAlert.h"

@implementation QuestionAlert

+(id)sharedManager{
    static QuestionAlert *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
    //defines a static variable sharedMyManager and is initialised only once in sharedManager
}


-(id)init{
    if(self = [super init]){
        //initialisations
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    //should never be called but here just for clarity
}
@end
```

EDIT after bounty: As suggested, I have used an UIViewController (say MagicViewController) in my Framework and have written touch gesture tracking snippets in that controller. I have taken the framework to my client and asked him to make all his classes a subclass of my 'MagicViewController', in order to store his touch data without him having to write any other code (of course, he will have to add our framework) as Embedded binary in his app. But he is not willing to make his classes a subclass of 'MagicViewController'. Is there any other way to achieve this purpose?I have seen some guys like appanalytics.io, appsee.io track touch data without having to write any code.

Comment: Use a base class.

Comment: Hey @rmaddy, thanks for the prompt response. A beginner here, can you explain in detail?

Comment: Another way to intercept touch events is to catch them at the UIWindow level.

Answer (score 3):

Common functionality belongs in a base class. Write your own custom view controller class called `MyViewController` (or some other useful name), have it extend `UIViewController`, and put your common view controller code into that class.

Then have all of your actual view controller classes extend `MyViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. This way all of your view controllers will have all of the common functionality added to your base class.

Your singleton class would have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Working on it. Will get back asap.

Comment: This works well. But my ultimate aim is to export this snippet to track touch coordinates in the form of a static library or a cocoa touch framework so that I can use it in my other applications. Using a base class cannot serve my purpose.

Comment: Why can't you have a base class in your library? Use the library in your other apps and have all of your apps use the base class.

Comment: Done. Upvoted but not ticked as of now. Is there any way I can still track the touch co-ordintes through a library without all view controllers subclassing 'MyViewController'. Through a singleton instance may be? Something what AppAnalytics and Appsee do?

Answer (score 3):

Just create an extension of `UIViewController` and let your client *(answering after the EDIT)* import your library header where this extension is imported. Once that is done, every View Controller will have the methods below:

```
extension UIViewController {
 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
 {
   //The Swift implementation you need to execute in all UIViewController instances
 }

 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
 {
   //The Swift implementation you need to execute in all UIViewController instances
 }
}
```

**EDIT:** The above is in Swift. In your case for Obj-C you can create a Category of UIViewController like the below:

```
@interface UIViewController (TouchesAdditions)
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end

@implementation UIViewController (TouchesAdditions)
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Began: %@ X location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.x);
    NSLog(@"Began: %@ Y location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.y);
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Ended:%@ X location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.x);
    NSLog(@"Ended:%@ Y Location: %0.2f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), point.y);
}
@end
```

Comment: extension of 'MagicViewController'? How do I do that?

Comment: If MagicViewController is of type UIViewController then you can add the extension in the MagicViewController.swift, the extension has to extend a native type like UIViewController so that your client doesn't have to change anything, and not extending the MagicViewController which is not available nor accessible to your client's developers.

Comment: what language are you aiming to write in this answer?!?

Comment: Only Objective C as of now. MagicViewController is of type UIViewController and all the touchegesture snippets are written. I am still not getting this extension thing.

Comment: @VamshiKrishna Extension is the Swift way of implementing a Category in Obj-C. Check the above edit. You can add a specific check to the methods to ensure that the code only executes on the desired view controllers.

Comment: Where do I put this code snippet? Im MagicViewController?

Comment: Hey! Looks like it is working. Just give me some time. I ll get back to you :)

Comment: Hey! I also want to add NSNotifications to follow the life cycle of app like UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification & UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification. What is the right place to add the in the library?

Comment: Also, what if the client also adds touches began/ended methods in his UIViewController? This will not work no!

Comment: You have to give the developer directions on how to use your library. First, for NSNotifications you can create a category of AppDelegate and override the functions you need like applicationDidEnterBackground or applicationWillEnterForeground. Second, your library has to explicitly state that the touches began/ended methods should not be overridden in any UIViewController where the library behaviour is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with method swizzling. No subclass needed.

Method swizzling is the process of changing the implementation of an existing selector. It’s a technique made possible by the fact that method invocations in Objective-C can be changed at runtime, by changing how selectors are mapped to underlying functions in a class’s dispatch table.
check: 
http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/